# PostGIS 2.0 and Self Intersecting Features

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis-2.0

I have a polygon feature class created by OpenStreetMap that is returning a self intersection error.  Is there a way to filter out these features? Can I just use a SQL statement to find the error polygons?

Comment: This is for you I guess http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidReason.html

Answer (score 3):

Query for

```
ST_IsValid([your geometry]) = 'f'
```

Comment: Not the best. `WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(your_geometry_column)` is enough. The function return a boolean http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html So my statement means filter to get only where the geometry is not valid.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing the query now.  Any suggestions on how to resolved self intersecting issues?  That seems to be my issue.

Comment: Interesting observation, when I added where NOT ST_IsValid(way) to my view in postgres, then tried to view the database view in ArcMap, I get the same self-intersecting error.

Comment: No wonder at all because NOT ST_IsValid selects everything that is *invalid*

Comment: I realized that, I meant to say, where ST_IsValid(way).  

The other interesting fact here is that when I did a straight up where Not ST_IsValid() query, it returned no rows.  So maybe it's a valid PostGIS geometry but not a valid Esri geometry?

Comment: Should I read literally that you did not give a geometry column inside ()?

Comment: Here is my select statement that should return only valid geometries: select osm_id, way from osm_polygon where ST_IsValid(way);

This should return invalid geometries: select osm_id, way from osm_polygon where not ST_IsValid(way);

Comment: Could you add into your question a couple of invalid polygons as WKT?

Comment: Do you think if I just ran an UpdateCursor on the table with buffer at 0 distance that might fix the issue?

Comment: Self-intersections are not so easy to correct automatically. You can use ST_MakeValid http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html but it splits self-intersections to new valid polygons and you may not want to create such. Best for all would be to go to OpenStreetMap and correct self-intersections there.

Answer (score 2):

Self-intersections are not as malicious as non-noded cross intersections. Here is some solutions 4 U:

Automagical fixes by ST_MakeValid:

```
update mytable
set way = ST_Makevalid(way)
where st_isvalid(way)=false
```

And similar, but using st_buffer:

```
update mytable
set way = ST_Buffer(way,0)
where st_isvalid(way)=false
```

If it wont help this will give you coordinates where intersections occurs:

```
select 
  abs(a1.osm_id) as OSM_ID,
  reason(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way)) as Reason,
  ST_asText(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(location(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way)),900913),4326)) as location
from 
  planet_osm_polygon a1
where 
  st_isvalid(a1.way) = false
```

You can load it into QGIS as query layer using this query:

```
select
  row_number() over() as GID,
  location(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way) as way
from 
  planet_osm_polygon a1
where 
  st_isvalid(a1.way) = false
```

If you're using osm2pgsql schema and you want to repair this in OSM project you can run this query and save result as XML file. If you'll open it with your browser you can look at this intersections in OSM or load them into JOSM to repair them (query not tested so might need some tuning) :

```
select abs(a1.osm_id) as OSM_ID,
    reason(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way)) as Reason,
    ST_asText(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(location(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way)),900913),4326)) as location,
    a1.tags -> 'osm_user'::text as USER,
    '<a href = "http://localhost:8111/load_object?new_layer=false&objects=r'||abs(osm_id::integer)||'">Edit in JOSM</a>' as josm,
    '<a href = "http://localhost:8111/load_and_zoom?left='||
    st_x(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(location(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way)),900913),4326))::numeric(6,4) - 0.0010
    ||'&right='||
    st_x(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(location(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way)),900913),4326))::numeric(6,4) + 0.0010
    ||'&top='||
    st_y(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(location(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way)),900913),4326))::numeric(6,4) + 0.0010
    ||'&bottom='||
    st_y(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(location(ST_IsValidDetail(a1.way)),900913),4326))::numeric(6,4) - 0.0010
    ||'">Edit in JOSM</a>' as Area_in_JOSM,
    '<a href = "http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/'||abs(osm_id::integer)||'">Show on map</a>' as OSM
from planet_osm_polygon a1
where st_isvalid(a1.way) = false
order by a1.tags -> 'osm_user'::text;
```